# I have problem when I try to put my project developed by django in a conteiner docker:

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

# Establece el directorio de trabajo en /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copia el archivo requirements.txt al contenedor en /app/
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Crea y activa el entorno virtual
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN /bin/bash -c "source venv/bin/activate"

# Instala las dependencias
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copia el contenido del directorio actual al contenedor en /app/
COPY . /app/

# Indica que la aplicación se ejecutará en el puerto 9005
EXPOSE 9005

# Define la variable de entorno para Django
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Arriendos_Backend.settings

# Instala Gunicorn

RUN pip install gunicorn


CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn_config.py", "Arriendos_Backend.wsgi:application"]
```

like you noticed Im trying to build the project with gunicorn
but the HTML doesn´t work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuZGk.png)

I try to take off the static files but the problem is still present

Answer (score 0):

The problem when moving to production is that gunicorn does not serve static files. Instead you would want to have another container running a webserver alongside of your gunicorn container (nginx or apache). This container will ship the html coming from gunicorn to the user, but will also ship the static files, coming directly from your file system (or from a CDN). I'll give you a roadmap to follow:

You want to run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your dev machine. This collects all static files in one folder. Deploy a nginx container and make sure, to copy just created folder over to that container. Within the nginx config you then declare different server blocks. You pass one url to the gunicorn container and let other url prefixes (your `STATIC_URL`) being handled by the filesystem of the nginx container.

Your gunicorn is sending the html of your python application to port 9005. This is where nginx sends the request and listens to the request to communicate to gunicorn. It is two services communicating to each other. The actual request by the user is sent to nginx (let's say on port 80) and not directly to 9005.

You can think of nginx some kind of a middleman collecting all the different pieces to send the final full response to the user. gunicorn only serves the html part coming from your django project. In your case the html does work but not the serving of the static files. Hence the lack of styling, no images etc.